# How can I add a hotkey to change screen rotation on Windows if the graphics driver does not supply one?

Tags: windows, display, keyboard-shortcuts

On some systems, there are <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Arrow</kbd> key combinations to rotate the screen.

But, this is dependent on the graphics card driver, for example, NVIDIA drivers supply this hotkey.

Is there any way to bind keyboard shortcuts to screen rotation independently of the driver?

Comment: AmourSpirit wrote a script that allows for screen rotation: http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/60911-script-to-rotate-screen-orientation-for-windows-7/ Tested working on my Windows 8 machine.